# Moving from a list within a list using aa for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The function below is faulty I need a function that is able to switch from list_[0] to list_[1] when it reaches the end of list_[0] which is the number 6.

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_one = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
list_two = [10,20,30,40,50,60]
list_ = [list_one , list_two]
k = 0
for x,y in main(number ,list_[k]):
     if x == number[-1]: 
         k+= 1
     if k == 2:
         break
```

Comment: what do you expect exactly from your algoirithm?

Comment: also, what is main?

Comment: I would advise you to change `list` variable name. It is a key word in Python.

Comment: (list is a built-in in python)

Comment: @quamrana sorry about that i have changed up the list name to list_. I just want to re-run the program with list_[1](list_two) after it finishes going through list_[0](list_one).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you could simply repeat the `number` list:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6] * 2
```

That way lists in loop will have corresponding elements:

```
number = [1,2,3,4,5,6,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6]
list =   [1,2,3,4,5,6,10,20,30,40,50,60]
```

I also recommend changing `list` variable name, as @quamrana pointed out that `list` is built-in in python.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am just trying to re run the code once with list_[0](list_one) and once with list_[1](list_two).